# Two Problems in Swift

Tags: swift

I am new to programming and I am making my first app in xcode. I keep getting these 2 errors with little to no information on them on the internet. They are as follows:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands type '_' and 'String'"

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands.

This is the code I have for it.

```
@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton){

    // V_1 = (M_3V_2-M_2V_2)/(M_1-M_3)

        var a = CurrentPH.text
        var b = TargetPH.text
        var c = WaterVolume.text
        var d = PHDownn.text
        
        var Answer = b! * c! - a! * c! / d! - b!
        Answer = PHOutput.text
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do arithmetic on strings. You need to convert them into numbers.

Comment: You know, if you named your variables `v_1`, `m_3v_2`, and so on, rather than useless identifiers like `a`, `b`, etc., then you wouldn't need that comment. You're just risking the chance that the comment and the real code go out of sync, and that'll get real confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [binary operators](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/23953/binary-operator), they need 2 operands to work with. Such as multiplication.

You cannot apply `*` (multiplication) on two strings.

The first error says that `You cannot multiply [anything] with String` and the second  that you cannot multiply 2 strings together.

It's not clear from your question what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @DeepBlue is saying, I believe what you are trying to do, is to calculate with the values from text fields and place the answer in a fifth text field, when you press a button.

That would look something like this

```swift
@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton){

    // V_1 = (M_3V_2-M_2V_2)/(M_1-M_3)

        let a = Int(CurrentPH.text!)!
        let b = Int(TargetPH.text!)!
        let c = Int(WaterVolume.text!)!
        let d = Int(PHDownn.text!)!
        
        let answer = b * c - a * c / d - b
        PHOutput.text = String(answer)
    }
}
```

Since none of the variables are modified, I'm using `let` instead which makes them constants.

Since converting a `String` to an `Int` can fail, for example if you type text into the text fields, it can result in a `nil` result. To simplify the formula the integer conversion is force unwrapped.